# Observable not updated from programatically changed INPUT, even when trigger()'ed

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, observable

This includes setting via just

```
.val();
```

and using

```
.val().trigger("change");
```

I've tried both.

I've come up with the simplest example I can manage.

http://jsfiddle.net/hEtE9/2/

If you click the button that updates the someText observable with some random number string, the computed updates as well. If you use jQuery to change the input both the text and the computed are not updated.

What's up?

Answer (score 1):

This has stumped me before. jQuery needs to be loaded *before* Knockout in order for `change()` or `trigger('change')` to change the view model.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.0.0.js"></script>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qP9NW/

Comment: This looks like a regression in Knockout 2.2. On my jsfiddle if you load knockout2.1 it works fine.